# Trouble mapping EDI message to XML using smooks

Tags: java, apache-camel, edi, smooks

I'd like to map the below ORDERS EDI message to xml using Smooks

```
UNB+UNOA:3+9313938000631:ZZ+9343015000575:ZZ+110210:0926+1++++1'UNH+1+ORDERS:D:01B:UN:EAN010'BGM+220+R-95300561X+9'DTM+137:20110210:102'DTM+2:20110211:102'NAD+BY+9313938000631::9'NAD+ST+9216GR::92'NAD+SU+963725::92'LIN+1++19300601396099:SRV'QTY+21:4'PRI+1E:5.412'UNS+S'MOA+86:21.648'CNT+2:1'UNT+14+1'UNZ+1+1'
```

1. What should be the values for the (based on above message) **segment**, **field**, **component** and **sub-component** in smooks edimap config below?

   <medi:edimap xmlns:medi="http://www.milyn.org/schema/edi-message-mapping-1.0.xsd">
         <medi:description name="Purchase Order" version="1.0" />
         <medi:delimiters segment="
   " field="+" component="'" sub-component="~" />
   </medi:edimap>
2. Where would I get a description of all the EDI Purchase Order fields with examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for the benefit of others.

1. `<medi:delimiters escape="?" component=":" sub-component="~" field="+" segment="'" />`
2. Found [this website's EDIFACT tutorial](http://www.edibasics.co.uk/edi-resources/tutorial-docs/index.htm) a very good resource for beginners. After that I read the [ORDERS spec here](http://www.unece.org/trade/untdid/d03a/trmd/orders_c.htm) a good read. Specifically the segment table. Also, Smooks has a website available on GAE (http://edi-to-xml.appspot.com/) that allows your to parse and convert a edi message to xml.